# Unable to write spark dataframe to gcs bucket

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The job is submitted and run successfully. But there is just no data in the bucket. How should I resolve it?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([["Amy", "lily", 12], ["john", "tom", 34]]).toDF(*["first_name", "last_name", "age"])
df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("age").option("path", "gs://my_bucket/my_table")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code from the question *configures* the write operation, but never triggers the write itself.

In order to actually trigger the write operation you need to call one of the `save` functions in the `Writer` interface.

For example, following will do the job:

```
df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("age").option("path", "gs://my_bucket/my_table").save()
```

or:

```
df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("age").save("gs://my_bucket/my_table")
```

or even:

```
df.write.partitionBy("age").parquet("gs://my_bucket/my_table")
```

---

Mode details:

`df.write` returns an instance of a `DataFrameWriter`; here is the API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter

`DataFrameWriter` API is consistent, in its spirit, with all other Spark APIs: it is **lazy**. Nothing is executed unless an action is triggered.
For this, instances of the `DataFrameWriter` behave similarly to a builder pattern implementation: subsequent calls to the `format`, `option`, `mode` et al. only configure the write operation that may be eventually executed. Once the operation is configured, you can trigger it by calling `save` or a similar method on this instance.

Similarly, `DataFrameWriter` also allows you to reuse the write operation multiple times (e.g., configure a base set of options and then call twice to write parquet and csv files, for example; or write to different locations, etc.).